# jquery how to display values in alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

this is my code please help me with the query

```
$("#update").click(function () {
    var security_code = (red[0]["id"]);
    var sector_class_id = (red[0]["cid"]);
    var sector_id = $("#s1").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/update",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ security_code: security_code, sector_class_id: sector_class_id, sector_id: sector_id }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {

            var updatedata = (response.d);
            var ud1 = JSON.parse(updatedata);

            udata = $.map(ud1, function (n, i) {
                var temp7 =
                {

                secr_code: n.SECURITY_CODE,
                sect_class: n.SECTOR_CLASS_ID,
                sect_id: n.SECTOR_ID
                }
                return temp7
            });

            $("#mod1").modal('hide');
            display();
            $("#t1").hide();
            $(".alert-succcess").alert();

            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $(".alert-success").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                    //$("#l1").val(security_code);//label values from db
                    //$("#l2").val(sector_class_id);//label values from db
                    //$("#s1").val(sector_id);// user selects n den updates value
                    $(".alert-success").slideUp(500);
                });
            });
        },
```

i want to show updated values in my  alert message along with the previous values which were updated what should i do
  what should i do??????

Comment: Where is error message ?

Comment: provide us the html of your alert please